# How to render Html elements to Excel using exceljs?

Tags: exceljs

How do I export excel sheets with HTML elements using exceljs?

I want to use `<p>Header </p>` such text for excel header.
but it should render only text not the whole html in Excel sheet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Rictext is one option but not sure it supports <p> tags. Have you found any solution for this?